# Mysql cannot connect remotly

Tags: mysql

my Mysql cannot connect remotly,it will give error 2003.
I am using Ubuntu 11.04, After I gave all permission to the user root it will give 111 error.

please help me.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as it's poorly formed and doesn't belong here.

Comment: This is unanswerable without a lot more detail. Where is the server that you want to connect to? Who is it hosted by? Does it have a firewall? What client are you using to connect? Are you getting error messages in addition to bare numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be because of your server configuration is limited to localhost.

just comment out the line 
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
in /etc/my.cnf

Try it!! Happy coding :)